# Node.js on a Raspberry Pi Zero W with dependencies not downloading automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord.js, raspberry-pi-zero

I Made a Discord bot, and I wanted to host it on a Pi, but once I got node.js working, I ran into a wall where I have npm installed, but the dependencies won't download with it. Can someone help me?

> Code

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/bot $ npm i discord.js
npm WARN deprecated snekfetch@3.6.4: use node-fetch instead
npm WARN discord.js@11.1.0 requires a peer of bufferutil@^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.1.0 requires a peer of erlpack@hammerandchisel/erlpack but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.1.0 requires a peer of node-opus@^0.2.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.1.0 requires a peer of opusscript@^0.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.1.0 requires a peer of sodium@^2.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.1.0 requires a peer of libsodium-wrappers@^0.5.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.1.0 requires a peer of uws@^0.14.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN greeter-bot@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN greeter-bot@1.0.0 No license field.

+ discord.js@11.1.0
updated 1 package in 24.205s
```

Comment: If I was you I would check the architecture of your dependencies. Mongo, for example, will only work with x86 processors and raspberry is ARM. If I am right, please let me know so I can elaborate an answser.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well I fixed it by first installing the npms on my pc to a specific folder then transferred it with Filezilla

Comment: This is a very case-specific solution. My answer will work both for you and others who have this issue. Please either edit your question to include a similar solution to mine, or just accept mine. Stack Overflow is a community site, and as such, this question and answer should be usable by other users, which this answer is not.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't recommend hosting a Discord bot on a Raspberry Pi, but to stay in line with your question, I'll assume you insist on doing so.

You can try two things:

If you have `apt` installed, run the command `apt install -a`, which will install all packages missing from the previous output.

The second way is to just manually install the packages it says is missing.

Go to the [npm repository](https://www.npmjs.com/), search the missing package, then download the version it requested in the output.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well I fixed the problem, he chose a different route.